# Refer to Laravel route that have a prefix - Javascript AJAX - Laravel 5.3

Tags: ajax, laravel, laravel-5, routes, laravel-5.3

I have a problem with my route files and refering to the routes with Ajax. Here is a snipit of all relevant routes and the ajax Code :

in the web.php ( base route file ) i'm including the routes I need

```
require_once base_path('routes/shoppingcard.routes.php');
```

Now in my shoppingcard.routes.php is this route group that bugs me

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'shoppingCard'], function () {
    // add Produkt
    Route::post('addToBasket', ['as' => 'addToBasket', 'uses' => 'Shop\Frontend\AjaxController@index']);
});
```

I want to refer to the addToBasket route but wasn't really successful until now

Thats my Ajax code:

```
$(document).on('click', '#addToBasket', function () {
    var quantitie = $('input[type=number]').val();
    $.ajax({
        type: "post",
        url: "/shoppingCard/addToBasket",  // <----- Route I try to refer to
        data: {'id': $(this).data("id"), 'quantitie': quantitie},
        dataType: 'JSON',
        success: function (data) {
           // not important
        },
        error: function (data) {
           // not important
        }
    });
});
```

Now I tried many things out to refer to the route correctly but I always get a 500 or a 404

I'm using Laravel 5.3

The error I currently get in my console:

http://mypage.com/shoppingCard/addToBasket [HTTP/1.0 500 Internal Server Error 49ms]

But the path (shoppingCard/addToBasket) looks totaly fine so why I get a error?
I'm a little bit confused about that

Thanks for any help!

Comment: The path looks fine, maybe check your controller

Comment: I did and everythings fine there.. I tried a return "hello" in the route like this: 

Route::post('addToBasket', function () { return "hello" } ); but this haven't worked either

Answer (score 0):

Try to use

```
$(document).on('click', '#addToBasket', function () {
    var quantitie = $('input[type=number]').val();
    $.ajax({
        type: "post",
        url: "/shoppingCard/addToBasket",  // <----- Route I try to refer to
        data: {'id': $(this).data("id"), 'quantitie': quantitie},
        dataType: 'JSON',
        headers: {
            'X-CSRF-TOKEN': '{{ csrf_token() }}'
        },
        success: function (data) {
           // not important
        },
        error: function (data) {
           // not important
        }
    });
});
```

I think you didn't use `csrf_token()`. I put it inside.

Comment: I have the csrf_token included in another file. The code works totally fine in another shop. If I change the route refering to my other shop, it works fine. So the javascript code is definetly fine!

Comment: ( but I also tried it now and it's still the same error )

Comment: Try to use get method and tell me its working or not?

Comment: That means your route is not working fine. I am giving you below procedure to add another route. Please follow and response me.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't notice you were using a custom route file. Have you mappedthe custom route file in the RouteServiceProvider? You can read it up here:  http://laravel-tricks.com/tricks/laravel-5-multiple-routes-files

Comment: No I haven't mapped the route file but I don't need to do that cause the new route files are still in the normal web.php file - I only include them. It's not really a total new route file - I have another shop with about 7 different route files without mapping them in the serviceprovider

Comment: You said the addBasket route is in shoppingcard.routes.php. That's not the default web.php

Comment: Okay I added the new route file to the service provider but this haven't changed a thing

Comment: Did you follow the steps listed? I am sure there's a problem with registering this file. You can remove the addBasket route and add to web.php to test if it works. If it works, then you know where the problem is coming from.

Comment: I tried to put my addToBasket route in the base web.php file and laravel can't find the route - I just don't know why - I also wrote a test route to the web.php and this haven't worked either. I'ts very weird

Answer (score 0):

I am giving you an example to create multiple Route. I took from the given [link](http://laravel-tricks.com/tricks/laravel-5-multiple-routes-files). Its an example, with this you can create your own route. Here are the Example:

> 1. create two route files routes.web.php and routes.api.php
>
>    1. edit the RouteServiceProvider.php file to look like the code below: (Note: you can add as many routes as you want, just follow the same logic.)

```
<?php

namespace App\Providers;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Support\Providers\RouteServiceProvider as ServiceProvider;
use Illuminate\Routing\Router;

class RouteServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{

    /**
     * This namespace is applied to the controller routes in your routes file.
     *
     * In addition, it is set as the URL generator's root namespace.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $webNamespace = 'App\Http\Controllers\Web';

    protected $apiNamespace = 'App\Http\Controllers\Api';

    /**
     * Define your route model bindings, pattern filters, etc.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Routing\Router $router
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function boot(Router $router)
    {
        //

        parent::boot($router);
    }

    /**
     * Define the routes for the application.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Routing\Router $router
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function map(Router $router)
    {

        /*
        |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
        | Web Router 
        |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
        */

        $router->group(['namespace' => $this->webNamespace], function ($router) {
            require app_path('Http/routes.web.php');
        });

        /*
        |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
        | Api Router 
        |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
        */

        $router->group(['namespace' => $this->apiNamespace], function ($router) {
            require app_path('Http/routes.api.php');
        });

    }
}
```

Please response me, it solve your issue or not.